# Очистка стека вызовов с ZeroMemory?

Tags: c++, стек

Пытаюсь очистить стек. Создаю структуру после этого помещаю её в стек и пытаюсь очистить его, но на дебагере ничего не происходит. Ни ошибки, ни чего вообще. Что я делаю не так, я хочу разобраться почему такой код не работает. Библиотека /MD оптимизация O2 размер стека 0x4000

```
struct stub {
    DWORD_PTR a;
    DWORD_PTR b;
};

int main() {
      foo1();
      foo2();
      foo3();
      foo4();

      stub stb;
      DWORD_PTR adr = (DWORD_PTR)&stb - 0x1000;
      ZeroMemory((void*)adr, 0x1000);
}
```

Этот код будет работать. Но мне нужно удалить верхние адреса стека.

```
 stub stb;
 DWORD_PTR adr = (DWORD_PTR)&stb; ////// - 0x1000;
 ZeroMemory((void*)adr, 0x1000);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99333/discussion-on-question-by-------zeromemo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На большинстве мейнстримовых платформ стек растет сверху вниз. Поэтому если вы хотите получить адрес где-то в *предыдущей* части стека, вам нужно *прибавлять* значения к текущему адресу вершины, а не вычитать их.

В частности, в вашем случае, если вы хотите обнулить регион размером `0x1000`, это значение вообще не должно фигурировать в процессе вычисления начального адреса региона.

Comment: В моём случае он начинается на старших адресах. Мне нужно очистить то что осталось в стеке от предыдущитх функций. Да и какая разница, почему +1000 работает а -1000 не работает. Почему? хотя если я сделаю так mov rax, rsp | sub rax, 1000 | mov [rax], 0 всё будет нормально я уже думаю просто написать всё на ассемблере

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович Я не знаю, что значит ваше "не работает". Пока что ваши рассказы про "не работает" - это какая-то бессмыслица. Все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Я проверяю на дебагере и стек не заполняется нулями если я делаю -0x1000 и всё прекрастно работает если я делаю +0x1000 но удаляет не в ту сторону что мне нужно. За пределы стека я не выхожу в обеих случаях. Размер стека 0x4000 я нахожусь примерно по середине.

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: Из того, что стек растет сверху вниз совсем не следует что адреса в памяти каким то магическим образом увеличиваются сверху вниз. Я же ясно написал, что никакого `+ 0x1000` по этой причине в вычислении стартового адреса быть не должно. Все у вас прекрасно работает и заполняется нулями. А то, что эти нули не попадают в правильное место - это ваши личные косяки. Вы пишете какой-то дикий бред в вычислении адреса, а потом удивляетесь, что нули не попадают куда нужно. Никакой ассемблер вам тут не поможет, потому что в ассемблере вы сделаете те же самые ошибки.

Comment: Прекратите писать чепуху про "не в ту сторону" и сначала разберитесь с тем, как устроена адресация в стеке. Без этого ничего не получится.

Comment: Я знаю как растёт стек от старших адресов к младшим. Когда я кладу stub она например будет размещена в стеке по адресу 0x899de00010
если я положу ещё одну такую структуру она будет размещена по адресу 0x899de00000. Когда функция foo4 начнёт свою работу стек вычитается sub rsp, 20 когда закончит add rsp, 20 после этого она положит мой stub и поэтому мне нужно отнять от стаба чтобы удалить то что оставила функция foo4 после себя в стеке. Я всё пытаюсь сделать правильно

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: Прекрасно. Что тогда означают эти магические значения `0x50` и `0x1000` и почему мы нам рассказываете, что у вас что-то "не работает".

Comment: Когда функции начали вызываться стек рос в сторону наименьших адресов например всё началось с адреса 0x899de01000, а закончилось всё на адресе 0x899de00000. Когда все функции закончили свою работу стек сдинулся обратно на адрес 0x899de01000, я кладу стаб и он получает адрес 0x899de01010 я вычитаю 10 а после этого ещё 1000 и хочу всё заполнить нулями. (10-50 без разницы это был тест, вычитал 2 раза просто для удобства мог отнять сразу 1050 или 1010)

Comment: немнеого опечатался с адресом стаба, 0x899de01000 - 0x10 будет адрес стаба, но в любом случае мне нужно вычитать но ZeroMemory не заполняет это нулями, кстати написал на ассемблере код, всё работает чётко, но хотелось бы понять почему это не работает на с++

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: Прекрасно. "Я вычитаю 10 а после этого ещё 1000 и хочу всё заполнить нулями" - отлично, вот там все и заполнится нулями. "но ZeroMemory не заполняет это нулями" - вы выдумывете. Именно начиная с адреса "я вычитаю 10 а после этого ещё 1000" все прекрасно заполняется нулями, как и должно быть. С чего вы взяли, что `ZeroMemory` чего-то не заполняет - я не понимаю. С чего вы это взяли?

Comment: стаб лежит в стеке по адресу 0x899de01000 мне нужно заполнить всё нулями от 0x899de01000 до 0x899de00000. 
Adr = 0x899de01000 - 0x1000 = 0x899de00000; ZeroMemory(Adr, 0x1000); Смотрю на дебагере никаких нулей не вижу.

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: Куда именно вы смотрите в дебаггере?

Comment: на стек на адреса с 0x899de00000 по 0x899de01000

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: Вы описываете какое-то невероятное и необъяснимое "магическое" поведение. У меня все прекрасно обнуляется в стеке. С какого адреса попросите - с такого и обнуляется.

Comment: можете показать код?

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович: https://pastebin.com/uhzXMYFm

Answer (score 0):

Тут вы смещаетесь на 0x4000 байт, а не на 0x1000 как ожидаете, т.к. работает адресная арифметика. DWORD_PTR + 1 это смещене на следующий 4 байтный объект.

```
DWORD_PTR adr = (DWORD_PTR)&stb - 0x1000;
```

Тут вы отчищаете только первые 0x1000 байт, а в дебагере смотрете на последние 0x1000

```
ZeroMemory((void*)adr, 0x1000);
```

Comment: наврядле, я же принтовал получившиеся адреса. они были верными

Comment: Навряд ли что? Смещение идет на 0x4000 байт, а не на 0x1000 это 100%, ZeroMemory очищает только самые "левые" 0x1000, а не 0x4000 это тоже 100%